# How to get the value of a property of a random turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I am creating an agent based model wherein I have a Boolean property called feature? for every turtle/agent. I need to set/ copy the value of feature? of a random turtle to another.
How do i achieve this? How do i complete this code:

```
 ask turtles[
    set feature? one-of other...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
ask turtles [
  ask one-of other turtles [set feature? [feature?] of myself]
]
```

But this asks **all** turtles to transfer their `feature?` to a random turtle other than themselves, which means that their own `feature?` could be reset by other turtles before they transfer it to another, and any given turtle could receive a `feature?` from more than one turtle.  Is that what you want, or are you asking only certain turtles to do this?